# magento2 - Authorize.net how to pass line items in request

Tags: products, payment-gateway, magento2.3.1, authorize.net

We uses magento 2.3.1 version and it introduce Authorize.net accept js method instead of direct post. its working fine but we want to send product data as line items.

How to add line items in Authorize.net request or how to override authorize.net vendor core files?

Regards
Hiren Shah